# Spring test - create first beans from test classes and then the real code

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

Question: how I can assure that, the beans from the test classes are created first in Spring?
Situation:
I have a Data Source which is provided at runtime an it is got through jndi.
At compile time I am creating one for an in memory DB and bind it to a jndi name. the problem is that the jndi lookup from the real code is executed first.

How I can assure that the test DS is created first and then the jndi lookup from real code is executed?

Edit after i found the solution.
The solution i found is:

There is RepositoryConfig.java and RepositoryTestConfig.java.
Before I was importing RepositoryConfig into RepositoryTestConfig.

I changed the approach:

- I made RepositoryTestConfig to extend RepositoryConfig
- I hided/override the DS bean into RepositoryTestConfig
- On the EntityManager I added the DS through Autowire

And the problem is solved 100%.

For the DS took through jndi lookup i created a separate test to prove the method, since the real method is hidden/overwritten now by the DS form RepositoryConfigTest.

Comment: Could you please update the code for datasource creation ?  is the code as follows ?`return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"))`

Comment: it is exactly like that. As I said, at runtime i it works perfectly, because the DS is already there. When tests are executed at compile time DS is created and binded to the jndi name. But the jndi lookup is done before the DS creation and not after.

Comment: Use Spring profiles for your test classes. Spring has a very neat approach for load the configurations as per the uses or profiles. If you want I can provide you some examples. Provide test-properties in src/test/resources dir.

Answer (score 0):

you should configure this with custom `@Configuration` class with `@ComponentScan` on your needed package

Comment: I need both configuration classes. I cannot exclude 1 with @ComponentScan. The only thing that i need is that Spring to execute first the TestConfig.java class to create the DS and bind it to a jndi name and then execute the RealCodeConfig.java class to get the DS through jndi. And through this, assure that the DS is already there when it is called through jndi.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`@Profile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html)

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    @Profile("test")
    public DataSource dataSourceTest() throws NamingException {
        return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup(env.getProperty("jdbc.test.url"));
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("!test")
    public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
        return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
    }
```

}

and from test class set the active profile as "test" , an example

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles({ "test" })
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class) 
public class AppTest {

}
```

Explanation

The `@Bean` creation is associated with a profile in the configuration .  When "test" profile is active the datasource instance with property entry `jdbc.test.url` will be created and for any other profile an instance of datasource with property `jdbc.url` will be created.

Note : You may separate out the test and prod bean configurations to different classes. The code shared is to help understand the `@Profile` usage

Comment: Why i should have Test code into real code? The test DS should reside into a test class, so all the code will not be present when the app is packaged to be deployed

Comment: You can keep the test code the way you prefer. I have added a note that this is an example to understand the usage

Comment: This [document](https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles) should give you more insight on this topic .Please refer the section _Integration Testing with Environment Profiles_

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the end:
Esentially there are 2 approaches:

1. use @Profile and @ActiveProfile
2. Hide the real/overide real DS though the extension of the real code config class

1.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(....)
@EntityScan(basePackages = "...")
public class RepositoryConfig {

    @Value("${ds-jndi-name}")
    private String dataSourceJndiname;


    @Bean("myDs")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(dataSourceJndiname);
    }

.....


}
```

2

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfigTest extends RepositoryConfig{

    @Value("${ds-jndi-name}")
    private String dataSourceJndiname;

    @Primary
    @Bean("myDs")
    @SneakyThrows
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabase datasource = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(HSQL)
                .setSeparator(";")
                .addScript("classpath:/inmemorytablesdefinitions.sql")
                .build();
        bindDS(datasource);
        return datasource;
    }
 ......
 }
```

Into the repositories that you test you do:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {RepositoryConfigTest.class})
public class AppRepositoryTest {

    private App givenApp;

    @Autowired
    private AppRepository appRepository;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
      ... whatever code
    }

 @Test
    public void shoudReadApp() {
        //given
         .....
        //when
           .......
        //then
        assert ...
    }
   }
```

Now in test compile time context we have the in memory DS, at runtime we have the real DS taken through jndi lookup. 
The thing that needs to be tested in + is the jndi lookup since the runtime DS is hided now.

The advantage of this is, that we are not forced to deal with maintenance of profiles. If you have yet profiles used in your code.